# QT Multithreading Data Pass from Main Thread to Worker Thread

Tags: multithreading, qt

I am using multithreading in my QT program. I need to pass data to the worker object that lives in the worker thread from the main gui thread. I created a setData function in a QObject subclass to pass all the necessary data from the main gui thread. However I verified the function is called from the main thread by looking at QThread::currentThreadId() in the setData function. Even though the worker object function is called from the main thread does this ensure that the worker thread still has its own copy of the data as is required for a reentrant class? Keep in mind this is happening before the worker thread is started.

Also if basic data types are used in a class without dynamic memory and no static global variables is that class reentrant as long as all of its other member data is reentrant? (it's got reentrant data members like qstrings, qlists etc in addition the the basic ints bools etc)

Thanks for the help

***Edited new content:***

My main question was simply is it appropriate to call a QObject subclass method living in another thread from the main gui thread in order to pass my data to the worker thread to be worked on (in my case custom classes containing backup job information for long-pending file scans and copies for data backup).  The data pass all happens before the thread is started so there's no danger of both threads modifying the data at once (I think but I'm no multithreading expert...)  It sounds like the way to do this from your post is to use a signal from the main thread to a slot in the worker thread to pass the data.  I have confirmed my data backup jobs are reentrant so all I need to do is assure that the worker thread works on its own instances of these classes.  Also the transfer of data currently done by calling the QObject subclass method is done before the worker thread starts - does this prevent race conditions and is it safe?

Also [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-qobject.html) under the section "Accessing QObject Subclasses from Other Threads" it looks a little dangerous to use slots in the QObject subclass...

**OK here's the code I've been busy recently...
Edited With Code:**

```
void Replicator::advancedAllBackup()
{
    updateStatus("<font color = \"green\">Starting All Advanced Backups</font>");
    startBackup();

    worker = new Worker;
    worker->moveToThread(workerThread);
    setupWorker(normal);

    QList<BackupJob> jobList;
    for (int backupCount = 0; backupCount < advancedJobs.size(); backupCount++)
        jobList << advancedJobs[backupCount];

    worker->setData(jobList);
    workerThread->start();
}
```

The startBackup function sets some booleans and updates the gui.
the setupWorker function connects all signals and slots for the worker thread and worker object.
the setData function sets the worker job list data to that of the backend and is called before the thread starts so there is no concurrency.
Then we start the thread and it does its work.

And here's the worker code:

```
void setData(QList<BackupJob> jobs) { this->jobs = jobs; }
```

So my question is: is this safe?

Comment: "the transfer of data currently done by calling the QObject subclass method is done before the worker thread starts - does this prevent race conditions and is it safe?" The `QObject` here doesn't matter. What matters is if the implementation of your method, and indeed of your entire class, is safe. How do you expect us to be able to decide that without you showing any code whatsoever for us to talk about?

Comment: "it looks a little dangerous to use slots in the QObject subclass..." That's a useless observation (you literally can't use it). A particular method, whether a slot or not, is either thread-safe or it isn't. If it's not thread-safe, then it can only be called from the object's thread. You should assert that it's being called so: add `Q_ASSERT(QThead::currentThread() == thread());` at the beginning of such methods. Thread-safe methods can be called from any thread. Invoking a thread-unsafe method safely invokes emitting a signal and connecting the method to it.

Answer (score 4):

There are some misconceptions in your question.

Reentrancy and multithreading are orthogonal concepts. Single-threaded code can be easily forced to cope with reentrancy - and is as soon as you reenter the event loop (thus you shouldn't).

The question you are asking, with correction, is thus: *Are the class's methods thread-safe if the data members support multithreaded access?* The answer is yes. But it's a mostly useless answer, because you're mistaken that the data types you use support such access. They **most likely don't**!

In fact, you're very unlikely to use multithread-safe data types unless you explicitly seek them out. POD types aren't, most of the C++ standard types aren't, most Qt types aren't either. Just so that there are no misunderstandings: a `QString` is not multithread-safe data type! The following code is has undefined behavior (it'll crash, burn and send an email to your spouse that appears to be from an illicit lover):

```
QString str{"Foo"};
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
  QtConcurrent::run([&]{ str.append("bar"); });
```

The follow up questions could be:

- Are my data members supporting multithreaded access? I thought they did.

  No, they aren't unless you show code that proves otherwise.
- Do I even need to support multithreaded access?

  Maybe. But it's much easier to avoid the need for it entirely.

The likely source of your confusion in relation to Qt types is their implicit sharing semantics. Thankfully, their relation to multithreading is rather simple to express:

1. **Any instance of a Qt implicitly shared class can be accessed from any one thread at a given time**. Corollary: you need one instance per thread. Copy your object, and use each copy in its own thread - that's perfectly safe. These instances may share data initially, and Qt will make sure that any copy-on-writes are done thread-safely for you.
2. Sidebar: **If you use iterators or internal pointers to data on non-const instances, you must forcibly `detach()` the object before constructing the iterators/pointers.** The problem with iterators is that they become invalidated when an object's data is detached, and detaching can happen in any thread where the instance is non-const - so at least one thread will end up with invalid iterators. I won't talk any more of this, the takeaway is that implicitly shared data types are tricky to implement and use safely. With C++11, there's no need for implicit sharing anymore: they were a workaround for the lack of move semantics in C++98.

What does it mean, then? It means this:

```
// Unsafe: str1 potentially accessed from two threads at once
QString str1{"foo"};
QtConcurrent::run([&]{ str1.apppend("bar"); });
str1.append("baz");

// Safe: each instance is accessed from one thread only
QString str1{"foo"};
QString str2{str1};
QtConcurrent::run([&]{ str1.apppend("bar"); });
str2.append("baz");
```

The original code can be fixed thus:

```
QString str{"Foo"};
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
  QtConcurrent::run([=]() mutable { str.append("bar"); });
```

This isn't to say that this code is very useful: the modified data is lost when the functor is destructed within the worker thread. But it serves to illustrate how to deal with Qt value types and multithreading. Here's why it works: copies of `str` are taken when each instance of the functor is constructed. This functor is then passed to a worker thread to execute, where its copy of the string is appended to. The copy initially shares data with the `str` instance in the originating thread, but `QString` will thread-safely duplicate the data. You could write out the functor explicitly to make it clear what happens:

```
QString str{"Foo"};
struct Functor {
  QString str;
  Functor(const QString & str) : str{str} {}
  void operator()() {
    str.append("bar");
  }
};
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
  QtConcurrent::run(Functor(str));
```

How do we deal with passing data using Qt types in and out of a worker object? All communication with the object, when it is in the worker thread, must be done via signals/slots. Qt will automatically copy the data for us in a thread-safe manner so that each instance of a value is ever only accessed in one thread only. E.g.:

```
class ImageSource : public QObject {
  QImage render() {
    QImage image{...};
    QPainter p{image};
    ...
    return image;
  }
public:
  Q_SIGNAL newImage(const QImage & image);
  void makeImage() {
    QtConcurrent::run([this]{
      emit newImage(render());
    });
  }
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  QApplication app...;
  ImageSource source;
  QLabel label;
  label.show();
  connect(source, &ImageSource::newImage, &label, [&](const QImage & img){
    label.setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(img));
  });
  source.makeImage();
  return app.exec();
}
```

The connection between the source's signal and the label's thread context is automatic. The signal happens to be emitted in a worker thread in the default thread pool. At the time of signal emission, the source and target threads are compared, and if different, the functor will be wrapped in an event, the event posted the label, and the label's `QObject::event` will run the functor that sets the pixmap. This is all thread-safe and leverages Qt to make it almost effortless. The target thread context `&label` is critically important: without it, the functor would run in the worker thread, not the UI thread.

Note that we didn't even have to move the object to a worker thread: in fact, moving a `QObject` to a worker thread should be avoided unless the object does need to react to events and does more than merely generate a piece of data. You'd typically want to move e.g. objects that deal with communications, or complex application controllers that are abstracted from their UI. Mere generation of data can be usually done using `QtConcurrent::run` using a signal to abstract away the thread-safety magic of extracting the data from the worker thread to another thread.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  My response doesn't fit here so I posted below.

Comment: Would you please extend your answer and include the case where we want to share a piece of data between main thread and the it worker object(s) (which have created in main thread and then moved to another thread using `moveToThread()` method)? Specifically, I would like to know how a piece of data, say a struct, which has been created in the main thread can be shared with its worker objects and all the threads be synchronized at the same time, i.e. they can safely read or modify the same shared data. If it can be done using signals/slots would you please include a minimal example? Thanks.

Comment: Typically, this would be done using a read-write mutex. Otherwise, you’d be using blocking queued connections to stop the thread needing read access until the thread nominally owning the data begins to execute code on the behalf of the invoking thread. This would be a rather unnecessary complication, although synchronized writing is comparatively trivial and non-blocking: emit a “setValue” signal, connected to a slot in the owning thread.

Comment: @KubaOber Thanks for your reply. And if a locking mechanism (e.g. mutex) needs to be used, how can it be shared between main thread and its worker threads? If we simply create the mutex in the mainthread and pass it to the workers in their constructors, doesn't calling `lock()` on the mutex in the worker thread result in the warning `QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread...`? I ask this because I shared a `QSerialPort` object this way and it gave that warning.

Comment: @KubaOber And if we use the "setValue" signal approach, it is possible that a worker never handle that signal if it is always busy in its initial slot (e.g. `run`) that has been triggered in mainthread as a result of starting its corresponding thread, right?

Comment: @KubaOber And doesn't the signal/slot approach induce a lot of redundancy and overhead, e.g. each thread have its own copy of the shared data, or each modification of data by one thread should be signaled to other threads and they update their own copy?

Comment: Having a mutex to access shared data doesn’t make a QObject usable from multiple threads — not without it being designed that way. QObject is a so-called active object: it can react to events. It’s intimately tied to the thread it’s in. I can’t imagine why would you want to access a QSerialPort from multiple threads anyway — it’s unnecessary. You should post a new question that actually lays out what for – or why – you want to do something, as well as your intended approach (if any) – and how it doesn’t work for you. None of it belongs in these comments.

Comment: I wouldn’t want to extend the answer, because it’s a whole another question that one could answer in a book-length work. But I have created a question of that nature that may be a starting point (look in the few questions I have posted — I have no link handy). It enumerates common solutions.

Comment: @KubaOber Thanks. Actually, I don't want to share `QSerialPort` (I know I need to create a serial worker and all the serial communications should be done through signal/slots with this worker). It was just a warning that I came across in one of my past projects and I just mentioned it (actually [you helped me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51852338/2099607) to resolve it). In my current project I am dealing with sharing one or multiple pieces of data (e.g. a struct, multiple ints, etc.) between threads and I thought this SO question and your answer seems relevant. Thanks anyway for the replies.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use Qt's mechanisms for passing data between threads with queues, you cannot call the object's function directly. You need to either use the [signal/slot mechanism](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html), or you can use the [QMetaObject::invokeMethod](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmetaobject.html#invokeMethod) call:

```
 QMetaObject::invokeMethod(myObject, "mySlotFunction",
                           Qt::QueuedConnection,
                           Q_ARG(int, 42));
```

This will only work if both the sending and receiving objects have event queues running - i.e. a main or QThread based thread.

For the other part of your question, see the Qt docs section on reentrancy:
http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/threads-reentrancy.html#reentrant

> Many Qt classes are reentrant, but they are not made thread-safe,
>   because making them thread-safe would incur the extra overhead of
>   repeatedly locking and unlocking a QMutex. For example, QString is
>   reentrant but not thread-safe. You can safely access different
>   instances of QString from multiple threads simultaneously, but you
>   can't safely access the same instance of QString from multiple threads
>   simultaneously (unless you protect the accesses yourself with a
>   QMutex).

Comment: 1. A `QObject` doesn't run an event queue. Event queues are per-thread, not per-object. 2. The sending side doesn't matter. You can emit a signal from any thread, including raw native threads.The thread where `main` executes wasn't started with a `QThread` either :) 3. The receiving thread needs a running event loop to process the events, but it doesn't necessarily need to be started using `QThread`. You could use `std::thread` to run an event loop; a hidden instance of `QThread` would be automatically constructed for it by Qt once you start the loop there.